# Blob Error with Active Storage Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blob, rails-activestorage

I've just upgraded a 5.1.4. app to 5.2 and am trying to swap out Paperclip for ActiveStorage. At the moment when trying to update an existing record with an image, I get the following error:

> Unable to autoload constant ActiveStorage::Blob::Analyzable, expected
>   /Users/Simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.0/app/models/active_storage/blob/analyzable.rb
>   to define it

In my model:

```
has_one_attached :pic
```

In my controller:

...

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @gin.update(gin_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @gin, notice: 'Gin was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @gin }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @gin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

...

```
 def gin_params   params.require(:gin).permit(:name, :text, :snippet,
 :pic, :slug, :abv, distillery_attributes: [:id, :name], botanical_ids:
 []) end
```

In storage.yml:

```
   amazon:
    service: S3
    access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
    secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
    region: xx-xxxx-x
    bucket: xxxxxxx
```

I set the access keys via `rails credentials:edit`

In development.rb:

```
 config.active_storage.service = :amazon
```

In my views:

```
<%= image_tag @gin.pic, class: "border shadow-lg" %>
```

I've been reading though http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob/Analyzable.html but it doesn't make too much sense to me.

The error has made me look for the file at `app/models/active_storage/blob/analyzable.rb` but I can't see it in my app?

What have I missed?

Comment: Do you have `gem "aws-sdk-s3", require: false` in your Gemfile? And did you do `rails active_storage:install`, `rake db:migrate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved

Whilst I already had `gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '~>1'` I didn't have `require: false`

Answer (score 2):

I've got exactly same error. For me it was because credentials for AWS S3 were missing (it was missing from *credentials.yml.enc*)

Answer (score 1):

I had this exception but the cause of my issues was that active storage was silently failing to load its configurations from storage.yml:

Loading the file in a rails console shows the exception (whereas rails swallows the exception when loading active storage config):

```
YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/storage.yml")).result)
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

I had a comment with an ERB interpolation that was invalid. Fixing this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Launch `rails active_storage:install` and `rails db:migrate`

Add this gem `gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '~>1'` and `bundle`

Delete your `credential.yml.enc` and your `master.key` if exists

Launch `EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit` and puts your credentials

And normally `rails s` it should work

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by updating `aws-sdk` from 2.2 to 3